# A strange phenomenon when use dozer in jpa project,why Mapping annotation in lazy load object can't work?

Tags: jpa, dozer

I met a very strange phenomenon when using dozer in jpa project.
I have a UserSupplier object and a Supplier object.

```
UserSupplier:
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id", nullable = false)
private Supplier supplier;
```

In my code I first query a UserSupplier List, then convert it to SupplierList.

```
List<Supplier> supplierList = new ArrayList<>(usList.size());
usList.forEach(us -> supplierList.add(us.getSupplier()));
```

Then I convert SupplierList to SupplierView List and return it to Caller.

```
BeanMapper.mapList(supplierList, SupplierView.class);
```

My dozer configure in these objects like below

```
 Supplier:
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Mapping("supplierId")
 private int id;

 SupplierView:
 private int supplierId;
```

Very funny, supplierId in SupplierView always 0(default int value),but other fileds can convert successfully, only id field fail. I don't why is this, why only id field can't convert to supplierId, but other fields could?

For above problem, there are below solutions

```
1. Change field name (supplierId to id):

 Supplier:
 // @Mapping("supplierId")
 private int id;

 SupplierView:
 private int id;

but Caller(front-end) have to change code.

2. Change fetchType to eager:

 UserSupplier:
 @ManyToOne
 private Supplier supplier;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because JPA uses proxy objects for lazy loading of single entity reference. Proxy object is effectively a subclass of your entity class. I guess that dozer can find `@Mapping` annotation only on fields declared in the class of given object, and not on fields defined in parent classes. Dozer project states that annotation mapping is [experimental](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/annotations.html). Therefore it is possible that it does not cover mapping class hierarchies well.

I suggest to try configure mapping of supplierId by other means (XML, dozer mapping API) and see if it works. If all fails, you could write a custom [MapperAware](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html#Data_Structure_Conversions) converter between `Supplier` and `SupplierView`. You would map source object to target object using supplied mapper, and finilize it by copying value of `id` to `supplierId`.

Comment: Thanks!  God! Annotation is experimental, now I know why it's function is so  poor. But other manners are so cumbersome, especially when use it with spring boot.  I'll search some better substitute.

Comment: I have come across [Model mapper](http://modelmapper.org). After my experience with cumbersome and buggy dozer I would try modelmapper in my next projects. If you try it, I'd be glad for feedback, as I have not tried it yet on any project.

Comment: Yeah, there are many substitute, like orika,jmapper,mapstruct. Because I prefer annotation configuration. Maybe I'll try jmapper(https://github.com/jmapper-framework/jmapper-core)

Answer (score 1):

After reading dozer documentation, I find some thing. After trying it, I got another solution.
That is add a dozer.properties into classpath, content inside is

```
org.dozer.util.DozerProxyResolver=org.dozer.util.HibernateProxyResolver
```

More detail please see
http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/proxyhandling.html